# HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest() always null inside Docker container - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Using the `ss-id` ServiceStack session cookie, I am tracking a user's session and revoking that session when the user has created too many sessions with the same account.

I have a CustomCredentialsAuthProvider that implements this interface:

```
public interface IUserSessionSource
{
    IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId);
}
```

Whenever one of my APIs calls `GetUserSession` in my Auth API,  I use the following code to try and get the value of the `ss-id` cookie:

```
public IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId)
{
    IRequest req = HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest();
    IAuthSession session = req.GetSession();
}
```

This works when I run my APIs localhost. As soon as I deploy my APIs in Docker containers `HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest()` always returns null.

I am running .NETCore in Linux (CentOS distro) Docker containers.

Any guesses to why HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest fails "inside" a Docker container?

Is there a more reliable alternate way to get the `ss-id` cookie value included in the HTTP request to my Auth API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest()` is only available in Hosts which allow accessing the HttpContext at runtime which by default is only classic ASP.NET Framework Apps.

Ideally you should avoid using singleton access to the Request Context and pass it in from `base.Request` in your Services instead, but for .NET Core App's you [can register HttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793) in your Startup `ConfigureServices()` but it incurs a perf hit:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: What about implementing IAuthWithRequest in my CustomCredentialsProvider? Would the PreAuthenticate method fire before GetUserSession is called?

Comment: @BrianOgden `IAuthWithRequest` is only for Auth Providers that authenticate with each Request, CredentialsAuthProvider doesn't, it sets up an Authenticated User Session upon Authentication then sends Session Cookies for subsequent requests. The `IRequest` is available everywhere, in Filters, Services, etc.

Comment: I tried implementing IRequest in my CustomCredentialsAuthProvider but the Request property was always null as well. I believe, if memory serves me correctly, Request was null localhost as well as inside my Docker container. Are you saying IRequest, if I implement in my CustomCredentialsAuthProvider will hydrate the Request property required for IRequest implementation?

Comment: @BrianOgden `IRequest` is always available within the context of a HTTP Request in an AuthProvider. For APIs that pass an `IServiceBase service` you can  access it from `service.Request`. Exactly which Request property are you saying was null?

Comment: I implemented IRequiresRequest in my CustomCredentialsAuthProvider, that requires the "Request property" I mentioned: public IRequest Request { get; set; } That Request property was always null in my CustomCredentialsAuthProvider

Comment: Is registering HttpContextAccessor just a performance hit on startup to register and instantiate or also for each each HTTP request?

Comment: @BrianOgden You can't just add `IRequiresRequest` interface to any class, especially not singleton instances. The `IRequest` instance is available in each API, e.g. in both `Authenticate()` and `TryAuthenticate()` APIs it's available from `authService.Request`. HttpContextAccessor is a perf hit at runtime since .NET Core has to manage copying over the current Request context in all the context switches.

Comment: So for every HTTP request there is a perf hit using HttpContextAccessor?

Comment: @BrianOgden Yes, which is why they disabled it by default. But you don't need to use it, use the available IRequest instead.

Comment: I am not understanding where IRequest would be available in a call to IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId). GetUserSession does not have a IRequest parameter. Where would I get IRequest from when GetUserSession is being called?

Comment: @BrianOgden you always need to pass it in, where are you calling it from? In your AuthProvider you can get it from `authService.Request.GetSession()`.

Comment: I have implemented this ServiceStack interface: public interface IUserSessionSource
    {
        IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId);
    } I am trying to get the current Request and the ss-id cookie in my GetUserSession implementation

Comment: @BrianOgden The purpose of `IUserSessionSource` is to return a populated UserSession from your back-end Auth Repository or other Custom data source you're using. Don't use it to return the existing stale session info, its purpose is to fetch the latest User Info and to validate that they still have access (i.e. are not locked out).

Comment: ok and I have a pretty serious business requirement that I need to meet and I just need to get the 'ss-id' that is in the Request to meet that requirement, is there a way to get the current Request using IUserSessionSource without the perf hit of HittpContextAccessor? Or can I intercept an access-token request and do some pre-authentication before the request contains to IUserSessionSource?

Comment: @BrianOgden You can't access Request Context data in a static context (what you're asking) without registering HttpContextAccessor to tell .NET Core to manage the Request Context for each Thread. The `GetAccessToken` Service which uses the RefreshToken to return a new JWT is interceptible like any other Service, e.g. you can use Request/Response Filters to execute custom logic before/after the Service is executed.

Comment: @mythz I'm running a classic ASP.NET Framework Application but TryGetCurrentRequest still always returns null. Any idea why?

Comment: @glazjoon if it’s a classic ASP.NET App it should work unless you’re not on the HTTP Request Worker thread, I.e in a background thread. Does HttpContext.Current return the context?

Comment: @mythz Hmm.. Well I don't have access to HttpContext at all since we have avoided System.Web, because we want to migrate to .NET Core in a reasonable amount of time. I'm guessing that is the problem?

Comment: @glazjoon `HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest()` needs to call `HttpContext.Current` to create the `IRequest`, not having a reference to System.Web isn't the cause but it will tell you that you're not in the HTTP Worker request thread since `HttpContext.Current` should always return the current context in ASP.NET, but if you want to move to .NET Core you shouldn't be relying on `HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest()` singleton access, instead explicitly pass the `IRequest` instance into the API that needs it.

Comment: @mythz Thank you, I get it now. We were trying to use IRequest.Items to cache some data during the request lifetime. Do you have a recommendation for how to do this using for example the ServiceStack Cache Client?

Comment: @glazjoon Can you please ask a new question with a clear example of what you mean and what your exact issue is. If you want to maintain per request data you should use IRequest.Items, also you should be passing in the IRequest instance instead of trying to access it via a singleton. Cache isn't for maintaining request data, it's for saving data against a key, there is no unique key per request unless you give it one (e,g. attaching a unique id in IRequest.Items) which you'd then need access to, which makes it pointless for request data instead of using IRequest.Items.